# How to use shared preferences to read data for all bottom tabs screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I need to save my data and then read it in all tabs and I try to save and read my data using shared preferences. Right now I have 3 screens, they are login, home, and profile screen. Inside home and profile, I use bottom tab navigator, so after users login (post their data and I save that data using shared preferences and I want to access that data in home and profile screen). What I make confused is... after I click login button, I navigate it to BottomTab file where ButtomTab file consist of home and profile screen and I get confused how to read my data in home and profile screen using shared preferences because after login, I navigate it to my BottomTab, not my Home Screen. Here is my code
main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

my Login Screen

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
postData() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('username', _username.text);
  Navigator.push(context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      new BottomTab()));
}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
             children:<Widget>[
               TextFormField(
                 controller: _username),
               FlatButton(
                 child: Text("Login"),
                 onPressed: () {
                    postData(_username.text);}),];}
}
```

my BottomTab file

```
class _BottomTab extends State<BottomTab> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _onTap(int index) {
    setState(() => _myindex = index);
  }

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(), 
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  Widget _myNavigation(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        currentIndex: myindex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <MyTab>[
          MyTab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          MyTab(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _myNavigation(_myindex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_myindex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my Home Screen

```
class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: Text("Hello ${...username that I want to pass}"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have choice, you can use `FutureBuilder` each time you want to display data from asynchronious source :

FutureBuilder :

```
class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<int> _getUsername;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUsername = SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) { 
       return prefs.getInt("username");
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder() {
    future: _getUsername,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
        // The value is not read yet
        return Text("Loading username...");
      }

      final username = snapshot.data.toString();

      return Container(
        child: Text("Hello $username"),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

---

Or you can use the provider package https://pub.dev/packages/provider to expose the value in the widget tree :

```
class _BottomTab extends State<BottomTab> {
// ....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider<int>(
      create: (context) async {
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return prefs.getInt("username");
      },

      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: _myNavigation(_myindex),
        body: PageStorage(
          child: pages[_myindex],
          bucket: bucket,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And read to read value :

```
Widget build() {
  final username = Provider.of<int>(context).toString();

  if (username == null) {
    // The value is not read yet
    return "Loading username...";
  }

  return Text("Username is $username");
}
```

The build method will be called again when the value of the `FutureProvider` is updated

---

EDIT : 3rd solution

```
class _BottomTab extends State<BottomTab> {
// ....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder() {
      future: _getUsername,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          // The value is not read yet
          return Text("Loading username...");
        }

        return HomeScreen(snapshot.data.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the first choice using FutureBuilder, but I get ```Loading username...``` in my screen, is that mean that username doesn't set in shared preferences?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do a misstake ? That should works. You will have "Hello null" without username. Check the conditionnal if inside builder

Comment: @uyhaW Try to add `await` for setInt in your postData method. I think you read the value too early

Comment: I just do the hot reload, and like what you said, I just get Hello null, is there any mistake when I set username in shared preferences?

Comment: it works perfectly now, like what you said :D, I add ```await``` in my code, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @uyhaW np, you can mark the answer as the solution. Happy coding

Comment: is there a way to prevent this condition```if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)``` because when I click another tab screen and back agai to my home screen, the data always rerender again

Comment: This condition is mandatory because you have to return a widget when you're data is not loaded yet. But if you want to avoid to load your data each time your `HomeScreen` is instanciated, you have to load the data by the parent. The second solution will be better.
Of course, you can also put the `FutureBuilder` in the `BottomTab` and pass data to the `HomeScreen` constructor

Comment: @uyhaW I edited my post with a 3rd solution. That would be enough for the use. But if you want to pass data through the tree, the provider would be simpler than pass data to each constructor

Comment: Hi.. @woprandi I have tried your second solution just now, and it works perfectly like what I want, your explanation really helps me soooo much in this situation (because I am new in flutter), big thanks for your helps and I really appreciate your helps :DDD

Comment: Hi.. @woprandi from your second solution code ```create: (context) async {
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return prefs.getInt("username");
      },``` I would like to know, is there a way to call more than 1 variable in my BottomTab? I mean I would like to pass 3 data to  all tabs that I have... from your code, it defines only 1 variable (username)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the SharedPreferences in your app wherever you want. Like you've said that you have to access your SharedPreferences data in HomePage and ProfilePage as well. So you are having two options now:

1. You can extract your shared preferences in your BottomTab page and pass that down to HomePage and ProfilePage.
2. Also, you can extract the SharedPreference in both the pages separately.

For extracting the SharedPreference you can refer the below code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var userName = sharedPrefs.getInt("username")
```

Comment: but when I click login button, should I need to pass username in my BottomTab? I mean, should I pass username here ? ```Navigator.push(context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      new BottomTab(...username value(?)...)));```

Comment: No, these SharedPreferences are global in nature. You can access those throughout the app without passing it.